# How do I create a calendar event that repeats every other week?

Tags: calendar

How do I create a calendar event that repeats every other week?

I'm using the default calendar app on the Droid X and the Xoom and I can't make an every other week appointment.   I can do this on the website without trouble.

The only options are every week and I don't see where I can say every (2) weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current calendar app from google now supports custom repeat appointments where you can specify repeat every 2 weeks.